# Is there a general regex method can combine those conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

In my code, I use four four regex conditions but it is too long, so is there simple or general method can combine these conditions?
I tried to `r'[(abc|def)+^((?!(xyz|efg)).)*$^.*[^,|.]$]{1,10}$'`but it didn't work...

```
s_l = ['abcabcabcabc', 'defdef.', 'sssssss', 'def', 'def,', 'xyzabc,', 'efgdefefg']

for idx, str_item in enumerate(s_l):
    if (re.match(r'(abc|def)+', str_item)  # find abc or def in str
    and re.match(r'^((?!(xyz|efg)).)*$', str_item)  # find xyz and efg not in str 
    and re.match(r'^.*[^,|.]$', str_item)   # comma not in the end of str
    and re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$', str_item)):  # find length of str smaller than 10
        print(idx, "True")
    else:
        print(idx, "False")
```

Comment: Maybe `if re.match(r'^(?=abc|def)(?!.*(?:xyz|efg))[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$(?<![,.])', str_item):`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your help again! if there is some digits and other char in the string, how to rewrite this: re.match(r'^.*[^,|.]$', str_item)

Comment: This is the point I do not quite get. You have `^.*[^,|.]$` and `^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$`, which contradict each other. What are the actual rules?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want there is no comma or period at the end of string and the length of str is less than 10 at the same time

Comment: This is `r'^.{1,10}$(?<![,.])'`

Comment: Is [this](https://ideone.com/eQ7oZe) what you are looking for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewW thanks a lot! Could you please write a answer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
 
s_l = ['abcabcabcabc','defdef.','sssssss','def','def,','xyzabc,','efgdefefg']
 
for idx, str_item in enumerate(s_l):
    if re.match(r'^(?=abc|def)(?!.*(?:xyz|efg)).{1,10}$(?<![,.])', str_item): #find length of str smaller than 10
        print(idx, "True")
    else:
        print(idx, "False")
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eQ7oZe) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bbkw2M/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=abc|def)` - no `abc` or `def` at the start is allowed
- `(?!.*(?:xyz|efg))` - neither `xyz` nor `efg` is allowed after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `.{1,10}` - one to ten chars other than line break chars
- `$` - end of string
- `(?<![,.])` - no `,` nor `.` allowed at the end of string.

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify the conditional expression quite a bit.

```py
regexes = (r'(abc|def)+', r'^((?!(xyz|efg)).)*$', r'^.*[^,|.]$', r'^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$')
for idx, str_item in enumerate(s_l):
    if all(re.match(r, str_item) for r in regexes):
        print(idx, "True")
    else:
        print(idx, "False")
```